# Offline Map for augmented reality application in android

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, augmented-reality

Ive just focused to develop an augmented reality map application for offline basis. Ive gone through [Mixare](https://github.com/mixare/mixare) codes and need to make offline(without internet) AR application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I recently created an offline application with mixare. I made it with the use of plugins. 
The project can be found here: https://github.com/abduegal/Arena-mixare

Along with some documentation on how to use plug-ins: https://github.com/abduegal/mixare/wiki

What I basically did was creating a launcher of mixare and bundle it with some plugins. I overrided some functions of mixare in my plugin's and by doing that I was able to create an offline version.

---

The OfflineConverter converts an online datasource to an offline datasource: https://github.com/abduegal/Arena-mixare/blob/master/src/org/mixare/plugin/util/OfflineConverter.java
**Note** that it is not able to convert audio and video markers.

And the offline capable marker https://github.com/abduegal/Arena-mixare/blob/master/src/org/mixare/plugin/OfflineCapableImageMarker.java 
is a plugin that overrides the default marker and opens an activity dialog instead of an webview.

You could also join the mixare google group and ask for help if neccesary. You will get faster responses there.

Answer (score 0):

AR, by definition, implies a location-based UI/UX.  Creating a map for an offline basis should be possible *if* you create a mode function similar to 'airplane' mode that would diable the GPS and location reporting.  (Also great to bug test AR apps in Airplane Mode!) - Hope that helps...